# Improper functioning of Timer1 in pic18

Tags: pic, clock, timer, crystal

I'm using pic18f controller and i am supposed to get a delay of 1 sec.I'm using an external crystal of 16mhz and this is the configuration bits that i have used in it.I have configured the timer1 and expects an interrupt when the 16 bit timeh register reaches the set point.
But Instead of 1 sec im getting a delay of 10 sec.Why is it like that?

[image: Clock source diagram]

The configuration bits were set as

HSPLL for Clock source and no CPU division selected.

This is the timer 1 configuration:

> ```
> T1GCON=0x0;
>
>             T1CON=0x71; //set the timer on with prescalar of 8 . 16 bit mode and the    internal clock
>             TMR1H=0x17;
>             TMR1L=0x70;
>             M_PEIE=1; //peripheral interrupts are enabled.
>             M_TMR1IE=1; //timer1 interrupt enabled.
> ```

And this is the configuration bits :

```
// PIC18F46J53 Configuration Bit Settings
#include<p18f46j53.h>
// CONFIG1L
#pragma config WDTEN = OFF                                                      // Watchdog Timer (Disabled - Controlled by SWDTEN bit)
#pragma config PLLDIV = 4                                                       // PLL Prescaler Selection (Divide by 4 (16 MHz oscillator input))
#pragma config CFGPLLEN = ON                                                    // PLL Enable Configuration Bit (PLL Enabled)
#pragma config STVREN = ON                                                      // Stack Overflow/Underflow Reset (Enabled)
#pragma config XINST = OFF                                                      // Extended Instruction Set (Disabled)

// CONFIG1H
#pragma config CPUDIV = OSC1                                                    // CPU System Clock Postscaler (No CPU system clock divide)
#pragma config CP0 = OFF                                                         // Code Protect (Program memory is  code-protected)

// CONFIG2L
#pragma config OSC = HSPLL                                                      // Oscillator (HS+PLL, USB-HS+PLL)
#pragma config SOSCSEL = HIGH                                                   // T1OSC/SOSC Power Selection Bits (High Power T1OSC/SOSC circuit selected)
#pragma config CLKOEC = OFF                                                     // EC Clock Out Enable Bit  (CLKO output disabled on the RA6 pin)
#pragma config FCMEN = ON                                                      // Fail-Safe Clock Monitor (Disabled)
#pragma config IESO = ON                                                        // Internal External Oscillator Switch Over Mode (Enabled)

// CONFIG2H
#pragma config WDTPS = 32768                                                    // Watchdog Postscaler (1:32768)

// CONFIG3L
#pragma config DSWDTOSC = T1OSCREF                                              // DSWDT Clock Select (DSWDT uses INTRC)
#pragma config RTCOSC = T1OSCREF                                                // RTCC Clock Select (RTCC uses T1OSC/T1CKI)
#pragma config DSBOREN = OFF                                                    // Deep Sleep BOR (Disabled)
#pragma config DSWDTEN = ON                                                     // Deep Sleep Watchdog Timer (Disabled)
#pragma config DSWDTPS = 8192                                                   // Deep Sleep Watchdog Postscaler (8.5 SECONDS)

// CONFIG3H
#pragma config IOL1WAY = OFF                                                    // IOLOCK One-Way Set Enable bit (The IOLOCK bit (PPSCON<0>) can be set once)
#pragma config ADCSEL = BIT12                                                   // ADC 10 or 12 Bit Select (10 - Bit ADC Enabled)
#pragma config MSSP7B_EN = MSK7                                                 // MSSP address masking (7 Bit address masking mode)

// CONFIG4L
#pragma config WPFP = PAGE_1                                                    // Write/Erase Protect Page Start/End Location (Write Protect Program Flash Page 63)
#pragma config WPCFG = OFF                                                      // Write/Erase Protect Configuration Region  (Configuration Words page not erase/write-protected)

// CONFIG4H
#pragma config WPDIS = OFF                                                      // Write Protect Disable bit (WPFP<6:0>/WPEND region ignored)
#pragma config WPEND = PAGE_0                                                   // Write/Erase Protect Region Select bit (valid when WPDIS = 0) (Pages WPFP<6:0> through Configuration Words erase/write protected)
#pragma config LS48MHZ = SYS48X8                                                // Low Speed USB mode with 48 MHz system clock bit (System clock at 48 MHz USB CLKEN divide-by is set to 8)
```

And in main.c  Only Led toggling is enabled.

And this is what happens in ISR

```
void isr_handler (void)
{

      if(M_TMR1IF)
    {
//        timer_flag=1;
        timer_inc++; //used for testing.
        if(timer_inc==1000)//5 sec
        {
            timer_flag=1;
            PORTEbits.RE2^=1;
            timer_inc=0; //reset timer.


        }
        TMR1H=0xc;
        TMR1L=0x49;


        M_TMR1IF=0; //clear the flag
    }//
```

I trust i should clear the 16 bit register too  right

Comment: How about showing your code?

Comment: Maybe you chose the wrong prescaler/postscaler values..

Comment: Ok.I'll post the code

Answer (score 2):

You have not posted enough of your code to be sure what is going on, but I'll make a guess that you're not resetting the timer after a 'hit' so you're getting 65536/0x1770 = 10.92 times the expected interval.

Comment: I have posted the ISR here.And i think you got the problem right.Wont the timer register reset after hitting the target? And what is the math behind this 10.92 second calculation .I would be happy to learn my failure side.:)

Comment: If you use a fixed comparison it will only hit after it rolls over, hence 65536=2^16. Normally you'd want to write a new comparison in the ISR that is offset (by 6000 in your case) from the previous comparison, and leave the timer to free run.

Comment: So what change should i make in ISr?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany that's a good idea, I never thought of that!